# ToBootstrap align with container width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below I've attached an image of what I'm trying to explain here. Basically I'm using bootstrap and I have two `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` to divide a row in half so that the background image of each extends the entire length of the browser window. What I'm trying to  do is have `difdivname` and `divname` text areas end at the width of the container.

I initially tried a background image for the entire row (with container), but because these collapse to a stacked view this won't work.

Again I'm not looking to just create a container as positioning will eventually be skewed at some point. Is there a way to prevent `difdivname` and `divname` from extending past the width of the container width?

[image]

### UPDATE:

I think we're moving away from the question a bit here. So below is a code sample to clear things up.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="difdivname">....</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="divname">....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing it this way takes the edge of `difdivname` and `divname` to the outter limits(!no container div). Now I'm trying to see if there is a way for `difdivname` and `divname` to take the frame of the container itself. I'm not looking for the `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` to be contained.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: How is this put on hold? A lot of effort to be concise here. Picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

U can make the width of the container stretch all te way by adding -fluid to the class like so:

```
class="container-fluid"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your detailing, if you want only the `textarea` to be of the size of the container to which they belong, why don't you give a `height: 100%` CSS property to the corresponding `textarea` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is clear and states this:

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.
>   Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.
>   Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

You can read it here: [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)

Now that being said:

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

or this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 ...
</div>
```

should do the trick depending on what you want. Looking at your set-up you might want to try this:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">Logo</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">We are supposed to be blue but coding enthusiast too lazy</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">We are supposed to be blue but coding enthusiast too lazy</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">We are supposed to be blue but coding enthusiast too lazy</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="difdivname"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="divname"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

### [Bootply fun link](http://www.bootply.com/pbezGoGENt)